# Netbeans 8.2 closed when open a file or project

Tags: netbeans-8, netbeans-8.2

I'm trying to open a file or project in Netbeans 8.2. Once I go to `File--> open File` or `File--> open project`,  the program is forced to close. Any Idea to recover please? Thanks in advance.

NetBeans Info:
**Product Version:** NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201705191307) 
**Java:** 1.8.0_111; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.111-b14 
**Runtime:** Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_111-b14 
**System:** Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb) 
**User directory:** C:\Users[MyUser]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2 
**Cache directory:** C:\Users[MyUser]\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2

Comment: What OS are you using? Have you checked **View -> IDE-Log** in NetBeans?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I use Windows 10

Comment: What type of file or project have you tried to open?

Comment: The folder I'm trying to open includes Java netbeans projects

Comment: Does this error happen on all (Java-)projects? or only some specific projects?

Comment: I happens once I click the `open file` or `open project` regardless the file type or the project type

Comment: You can try to delete: **<nb-user-directory>/var/cache** when NetBeans is closed (for exact folder location, look at : **HELP -> About -> Cache directory** in NB), after that, try again...

Comment: I did, still the same problem occurs

Comment: Which Java Version are you using to start NB (**Help -> About -> Java**)? You should include all those informations in your question. (you can also try to delete or rename the whole user-folder **Help -> About -> User directory**) Can you create a new project?

Comment: It is : `Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201705191307)
Java: 1.8.0_111; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.111-b14
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_111-b14
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)
User directory: C:\Users\[MyUser]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2
Cache directory: C:\Users\[MyUser]\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2`

Comment: I deleted the user folder too, no avail

Comment: Can you create new projects? Can Java read the filesystem (can you browse the filesystem with any other Java-App)? You can try to find some helpful infos in  **<nb-user-directory>/var/log**

Comment: Yes, can for all these you mentioned. The problem not with the java files. As mentioned, once I click open file or project, the netbeans IDE disappears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue by installing newer version of JDK than the one I had.

Comment: Can confirm, I've bumped version 1.8.0_131 to 1.8.0_261 and I worked

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem: When I opened a new project, Netbeans 8.2 immediately crashed. I deleted my God Mode folder which was on the Desktop and after all was ok.